# Restore MySQL Dump by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, restore, mysql-error-1064, dump

I've bought a Droplet on Digital Ocean, I've installed LEMP with Ubuntu 16.04 and PHPmyadmin..
I've uploaded a .sql dump on www/db dir and I'm trying to restore the dump by PHP..
This is the code:

```
<?php

// Name of the file
$filename = 'db/commgest.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = 'localhost';
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = 'xxx';
// Database name
$mysql_database = 'fluppi';

$restore = "mysql --user={$mysql_username} --password={$mysql_password} --database={$mysql_database} < $filename";

if(exec($restore)){
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. What is the issue?

Comment: just few advices:
1. use full path ti your filename
2. use `escapeshellarg` function for escape password, as password may contain special characters.
`$mysql_password = escapeshellarg('xxx');`

Answer (score 0):

why not with `mysql` command line ?

```
mysql -u username -p -h localhost fluppi < www/db/file.sql
```

Comment: "Need" is largely subjective. What requirements do you have?

Answer (score 0):

By your comment to @Being Sunny's answer, im guessing you are using shared hosting.

Log onto the PHPMyAdmin and upload the .sql file there. Or copy the MySQL code in the .sql file and execute it using PHPMyAdmin (or, not advised, PHP)

Another option is to read the .sql file, and execute the statements at every `;` using PHP

Comment: I've necessity to aumatizate the creation of new database and structure with PHP..!
I need to create a demo of my software dinamically for my clients.. I need this in PHP!

Comment: @LuigiMdg you mentioned nothing in your initial question about creating a new database. You initial question is nothing like what you just said you need to do... Or posted what error you are getting.

Comment: Ho un codice per la creazione del database. Prendi a me il codice PHP per ripristinare il dump .. Perchè mi prendi un problema? Tu mi dici che non usi PHP o l'obiettivo dei miei codici. Perché?
My question is: HOW TO RESTORE A SQL DUMP BY PHP???
.

Comment: @LuigiMdg as soon as you stop writing in English, I cant help you.